# Creating multiple array lists via user request (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create array lists for entry data, i.e. person's information, but I'm wanting to create new lists depending on user request (the user types in an int for example, then the method produces x ArrayLists depending on what x is, for storing data in more than one list, if they require it.)

I.e. the user can create multiple lists if they wish, then add in the data, how do you do this? 
I can't figure out how to do it and it's annoying me lol, if my explanation is vague, do tell me and i'll try to explain again... (Not the best at giving explanations, sorry, hope you all get what i mean).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single `ArrayList` that will contain all of the user's `ArrayList`'s:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    lists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Then to add something to list number `n`:

```
lists.get(n).add("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you are planning seems ugly. But nothing is impossible.

```
public List<List<yourDataType>> creatList (int x) {
    List<List<yourDataType>> l = new ArrayList<List<yourDataType>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        l.add(new ArrayList<yourDataType>());
    return l;
}
```